# IS NOT NULL giving null values

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have the following PHP code using PDO. I want rows with empty values to not appear in the results. How do I achieve this, and what am I doing wrong below?

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    echo "Connected to $dbname at $host successfully.";
    $sql = 'SELECT * 
            FROM as_questions 
            WHERE Answer IS NOT NULL';

    $q = $conn->query($sql);
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} catch (PDOException $pe) {
    die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: *"i want rows with empty values to not appear in the table."* - **A:** NULL `!=` empty. `if($row['x'] == NULL){...} else{ :p }`

Comment: `NULL` is different from a blank string, so you might want to change your `WHERE` clause to `WHERE Answer IS NOT NULL and Answer != ''`

Comment: @AlexAndrei i used WHERE Answer IS NOT NULL and Answer != '''; and  i am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '''' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: @alex thanks that works :) i had to edit a little bit  my code. changed  $sql = ' ' to  $sql = " "

Comment: @MohamedAthif it's because you used double quotes to store the query. Use like this `$sql = 'select .... where ... and Answer != "" '`;

Comment: @AlexAndrei yes. i just figured that out :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As above suggested by two persons (Fred -ii and Alex Anderi) please change your query like below:-

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM as_questions WHERE Answer !=''";
```